# Apache HTTP server STIG rule

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd.conf, security

I am new to setting up `Apache HTTP` and have to STIG the Apache HTTP 2.2 I have running. (http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/app-security/web-servers/Pages/index.aspx). For one of the rules it says the following

```
Edit the httpd.conf file and add one of the following to the enabled Options directive:

+IncludesNoExec
-IncludesNoExec
-Includes

Remove the ‘Includes’ or ‘+Includes’ setting from the options statement.
```

I went to the `httpd.conf` file. However I am confused on where I would put those lines. Does anyone have any insight into these `Options directive` and where to set them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive must be given for the directories containing the shtml files (typically in a `<Directory>` section, but this directive is also valid in .htaccess files if AllowOverride Options is set).